# How can I make sure the stopwatch function will keep on running on mobile browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to learn the basics of jQuery by building certain things and now it's my turn for a stopwatch (which will be used by mobile visitors).

I currently have this: [codepen](https://codepen.io/fayaye/pen/YOQLXw)

**html**

```
<span id="hours"></span> u | 
<span id="minutes"></span> m | 
<span id="seconds"></span> s
<button onclick="tickTock()">Start</button>
```

**js**

```
function tickTock () {

    var start = -1;

    function pad(val) { return val > 9 ? val : "0" + val; }
    setInterval(function () {
        $("#seconds").html(pad(++start % 60));
        $("#minutes").html(pad(parseInt(start / 60, 10) % 60));
        $("#hours").html(pad(parseInt(start / 3600, 10)));
    }, 1000);
}
```

After testing for a while I've noticed that after a certain period the time shown isn't correct anymore without closing the tab or browser. I want to achieve maximum reliability regarding the time shown and the time which has passed. The deviation only seems to appear on mobile devices.

Since I'm a beginner I don't know where to start. Is it even possible using js/jQuery? 
If you could point me in the right direction that would be appreciated.

Comment: not sure I really understand your question but if the problem is keeping time why not call getTime() every once in a while and calibrate your stop watch as needed?

Comment: `setInterval` is not accurate enough to be used as a timing device over long periods like this.

Comment: @DCR that makes way more sense, my bad!

Comment: @Carcigenicate I wans't ware of that, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Your code can be reworked to store the start time, then to display the difference between the current time and the start time, rather than manually incrementing every second.

This way, if your code gets shelved because it's in the background, the correct time will be calculated.

```
function tickTock () {

    var startTime = new Date();

    function pad(val) { return val > 9 ? val : "0" + val; }

    setInterval(function () {
        var currTime = new Date();
        var elapsedMs = currTime.getTime() - startTime.getTime();
        var elapsedSeconds = elapsedMs * 1000;
        $("#seconds").html(pad(elapsedSeconds % 60));
        $("#minutes").html(pad(parseInt(elapsedSeconds / 60, 10) % 60));
        $("#hours").html(pad(parseInt(elapsedSeconds / 3600, 10)));
    }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: jinx :)  We posted around the same time.

Comment: Thank you very much for your clear answer! Just as I've said to Harry, comparing your function will be a real lesson for me and clear a lot of thing up.

Answer (score 1):

The set interval is only semi accurate and does not guarentee you the function runs exactly at 1 second intervals.  You could start by taking the timestamp of when the function started and then using your ticktock function to subtract the previous timestamp from the current timestamp and then perform the necessary updates to the ui.  I'll leave the padding and rounding out to make the example easy to follow.

```
function ticktock(){
  var start = new Date().valueOf();

  setInterval(function(){
    var now = new Date().valueOf();
    var elapsed = (now - start) / 1000;

    var seconds = elapsed % 60;
    var minutes = (elapsed / 60) % (60);
    var hours = (elapsed / (60 * 60)) % (60);

    $("#seconds").html(seconds);
    $("#minutes").html(minutes);
    $("#hours").html(hours);

  }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your clear answer Harry!  

I've struggled storing the sec/min/hours as variables and that's why I couldn't get any further I believe. Comparing the structure of your function to mine will be a real lesson for me and clear a lot of things up.